# Geographical data clustering and ploting in R

Tags: r, geolocation, cluster-analysis

I am working with dataframe which has lat and long coordinates. I want to cluster those coordinates based on their location closeness in R and then plot it on some map.
I am able to plot the points on map with leaflet package,which gives me nice map layout and lat and long coordinates. Just don't know how to cluster those points lets say in 3 clusters. Will k-means clustering appropriate for this kind of problems? Or do I have to apply some distance metrics and then use clustering algorithm. I am bit confused with online literature available on clustering of geographic data. 
Here is what I am doing in R

```
map <- leaflet() %>%
     addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
     addMarkers(lng=df_final$order_long, lat=df_final$order_lat)

map
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you help clarify your question: Do you already know the lon/lat coordinates about which you would like to cluster your data or are you trying to determine the ideal centroids based on your data?

If you know the coordinates of each centroid, then you could just run your data through the kmeans algorithm with a max iteration of one.  The following would do that:

```
set.seed(1)
centroids <- data.frame(lat=1:3, lon=4:6) # Input the coordinates for your centroids here
locations <- data.frame(lat=runif(50,1,3), lon=runif(50,4,6))
kmeans(locations, centroids, iter.max=1) # Set your initial centroids and then iter once
```

If you do not know the coordinates and want kmeans to find them for you, then just increase iter.max or leave it as default (10).

Comment: No I don't know the centroids about which to cluster. I am working with one online food ordering application and want to figure out clusters with order locations. Lets say there are 50 orders coming in from different locations then I want to group those order in 3 clusters.

Comment: Ok, thanks that is helpful.  You could definitely use kmeans to cluster those:
`
    kmeans(locations, 3) # Assigns each location to one of three centroids
`
That would assign each location to one of 3 (or however many you choose) centroids.  One thing to note is that if you are trying to determine optimal delivery times, it may not be purely a function of distance, in which case clustering may not be ideal.  Instead, you could potentially measure "path length" and optimize for that.  e.g. Measure the distance each of the 3 delivery drivers travels in traversing their routes.

Comment: Do *not* use k-means on latitude/longitude data. Earth is a sphere, not a 2d grid. You want geo distance, not least-squares.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked several times here, please use search.

k-means is a bad choice for such data:

1. how do you find k?
2. k-means uses squared-Euclidean but you want a spherical geo-distance
3. k-means is sensitive to outliers

If you google a little bit, you will find examples why this does not work well. Instead, have a look at OPTICS for example.